# Using query to parse json arrays in Hive

Tags: mysql, json, hive

```
{"a1":{"id":a1,.....,"myinput":null},"a2":{"id":a2,....,"myinput":"1234"}, "a3":{"id":a3,....,"myinput":"abc"}}
```

Hi guys, I'm currently learning to use `hive` (since it likes SQL). I would like to ask about doing query in Hive to separate the array into different parts. Since my field has json type (like example above), may I know that how can I separate myinput into 3 different columns? I want it something look like:

```
column1     column2      column3
null          1234        abc
```

Comment: HiveQL is not the same as MySQL.

Comment: Okay so that is the new thing that I learnt from you. But do you know how can I put my query about my problem? I tried to search but I cannot find any solution, since in the "..." above there are quite a few more like "name", "school", etc

Comment: No, I don't know anything about Hive. I saw this question because of the mysql tag, then I saw that it was wrong.

Comment: What programming language are you using to connect to Hive?

Comment: hi, I'm using SQL-style to do the queries

Comment: That's not a programming language. I mean something like PHP, C, Java. The language that's going to get the JSON object and then create the SQL query from it.

Comment: The values you want to insert are `object.a1.myinput`, `object.a2.myinput`, and `object.a3.myinput`. Convert this to whatever the corresponding syntax is in your language, and insert them into the 3 columns in the table.